# How do I tell linkify not to underline links?

Tags: android, underline, linkify

Is there any way to tell linkify not to underline my links?  I am already using `textView.setLinkTextColor(stateList)` to change the color, but I'd like to remove the underline that is inserts on the link.

Is this even possible?

Comment: is there any update about this , i am trying to implement same behaviour

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4096851/remove-underline-from-links-in-textview-android for one possible approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    TextView tv = new TextView(this);
     SpannableString ss = new SpannableString(
     ""+getString(R.string.nonlinktext)+"\n"+getString(R.string.linkedtext)+"");
     ss.setSpan(new URLSpan(getString((R.string.linkedtext))), ss.length() - numberofcharactersinlink, ss.length(),Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
```

I managed to get this working using this implementation. A bit of a hack but it works all the same.

Comment: sorry the R.string.LearnMore should be R.string.linkedtext