# Linkify in android TextView

Tags: android, hyperlink, design-patterns

I have a text view with text" This is a product developed by XYZ. For more queries, mail us at info@abc.com. And I have linkified "info@abc.com". But the problem is, whenever I touch any area below the textview, it gets linked to the email. How Do I make sure, the link has to happen only on clicking info@....I used patterns, Linkify.EMAIL_ADDRESS..nothing seem to work...kindly suggest some answers

Comment: **[Custom Link Patterns Using Regular Expression](http://www.indelible.org/ink/android-linkify/) might be helpful**

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I had problems with automatic links, so I turned it off and instead I am using html formating of the text plus this code:

```
TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextBox);
textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(strText));
```

An email link goes `<a href="mailto:my@email.com">my@email.com</a>`

Comment: Works, but the text is rendered with an underline. How to remove it?

Comment: Here is one way to do it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4096851/remove-underline-from-links-in-textview-android

Comment: Took me an hour to figure it out, but it CRITICAL to call setMovementMethod BEFORE setText on the TextView. Good example.

Comment: All my "problems" with html text , spannables and weird weird link recognition where gone when simply removing all linkify methods and just setMovementMethod()   ( with clickable , etc)

Answer (score 17):

```
 android:autoLink="web"
```

Comment: This only works for links that are the url themself. With this you cannot f.e. link the word `Google` to `google.com`.

Answer (score 0):

Try using HTML formatting i.e. anchor tag for the link.

Answer (score 0):

Method using `Linkify` Class:

```
myTextView.setAutoLinkMask(Linkify.EMAIL_ADDRESSES);
myTextView.setLinksClickable(true);
```