# Remove underline in Android textview Autolinks

Tags: android, textview, android-textattributes

In my Android application I have to make some Auto links. So I used `android:autoLink="all"` property for the `TextView` as I have email, phone numbers and web links.

The problem is it creates an underline which I don't want. I found this [LINK](http://www.evilcodingmonkey.com/2011/06/07/remove-underline-from-android-textview-link/). But isn't there any easy way to remove this underline? Here in this example I guess it will only work for web links. I have phone numbers and email links as well.

Comment: I think this is the best solution. Its a quit a lot of work to remove the line for every single textview but there is no alternative. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4096851/remove-underline-from-links-in-textview-android