# Textview linkify without changes?

Tags: android, styles, textview, linkify

Is it possible to linkify a textview without the content changing colors (both before and after selection)and getting underlined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the attribute `android:textColorLink` with a ColorStateList file. I'm not sure regarding the underlining though.

Comment: This together with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4096851/remove-underline-from-links-in-textview-android did the trick.