# How to Remove Underline from hyperlink's text in android ?

Tags: android

I have Button and its text, I retrive it from string.xml i.e. 
I have declared a Button text in res/values in strings.xml like

```
<string name="Google"><a href=""http://www.google.com\">Google</a></string>
```

I removed its text color from blue to white but how do I remove its underline?
in my .java file I am using only `setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());` to make the link clickabale... I didn't use `Linkify`, webview or anything like form.Html...
everything works fine. I just want to remove the underline below that "Google" text...
Is there any way to do this in the xml?

I even used `android:autoLink="all"`. But when I used that, the text and button color changes and I dont want that.

Please Help.

Comment: There is an awesome answer for this here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4096851/remove-underline-from-links-in-textview-android

Comment: yeah before posting question I cheked that answer but I mentioned here already that I didin't use Linkify or anything else other than 
setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
but thanks anyways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after trying a lot finally i found the solution.
I removed the link from string.xml
and added this code in my java file.

```
Button btnGoogle = ( Button GoogleAlert.findViewById(
                R.id.btnGoogle );
            btnGoogle.setMovementMethod(
                LinkMovementMethod.getInstance() );
            btnGoogle.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onClick( View v )
                {        
                    Uri uri = Uri.parse(
                        "http://www.google.com" );
                    Intent intent = new Intent( Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri );
                    startActivity( intent );
                    buyAlert.dismiss();
                }
            } );
```

and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 9):

```
TextView text=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);   

    String value = "<html> click to go <font color=#757b86><b><a href=\"http://www.google.com\">google</a></b></font> </html>";
Spannable spannedText = (Spannable)
                Html.fromHtml(value);
text.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());

Spannable processedText = removeUnderlines(spannedText);
        text.setText(processedText);
```

here is your removeUnderlines()

```
public static Spannable removeUnderlines(Spannable p_Text) {  
               URLSpan[] spans = p_Text.getSpans(0, p_Text.length(), URLSpan.class);  
               for (URLSpan span : spans) {  
                    int start = p_Text.getSpanStart(span);  
                    int end = p_Text.getSpanEnd(span);  
                    p_Text.removeSpan(span);  
                    span = new URLSpanNoUnderline(span.getURL());  
                    p_Text.setSpan(span, start, end, 0);  
               }  
               return p_Text;  
          }
```

also create class URLSpanNoUnderline.java

```
import co.questapp.quest.R;
import android.text.TextPaint;
import android.text.style.URLSpan;

public class URLSpanNoUnderline extends URLSpan {
    public URLSpanNoUnderline(String p_Url) {
        super(p_Url);
    }

    @Override
    public void updateDrawState(TextPaint p_DrawState) {
        super.updateDrawState(p_DrawState);
        p_DrawState.setUnderlineText(false);
        p_DrawState.setColor(R.color.info_text_color);
    }
}
```

using this line you can also change the color of that text          `p_DrawState.setColor(R.color.info_text_color);`

Comment: I get grey links this way

Comment: p_DrawState.setColor(R.color.info_text_color); using this you can change the color of hyperlink text......                                    String value = "<html> click to go <font color=#757b86><b><a href=\"http://www.google.com\">google</a></b></font> </html>"; change color here for other color

Answer (score 3):

**Kotlin has Textview extension for removing underline**

```
fun TextView.removeLinksUnderline() {
    val spannable = SpannableString(text)
    for (urlSpan in spannable.getSpans(0, spannable.length, URLSpan::class.java)) {
        spannable.setSpan(object : URLSpan(urlSpan.url) {
            override fun updateDrawState(ds: TextPaint) {
                super.updateDrawState(ds)
                ds.isUnderlineText = false
            }
        }, spannable.getSpanStart(urlSpan), spannable.getSpanEnd(urlSpan), 0)
    }
    text = spannable
}
```

**Usage:**

```
txtView.removeLinksUnderline()
```

Answer (score -1):

You add `style=\"text-decoration:none\"` to your `<a>` tag.

For more information on how your string resources should be formatted, check out the [String Resources Documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html).

Comment: Thanks ! But I did it, but it does not work..the underline still remained below text.

Comment: Please post the complete `<string>` tag, with the modification I mentioned.

Comment: here is my string tag
    <string name="Google"><a style="text-decoration:none\" href="http://www.google.com\">Google</a></string>

Comment: Try this:
`<string name="Google">"<a style='text-decoration:none' href='google.com'>Google</a>"</string>`.

Comment: sorry sir, I tried it, but it does not work..the underline still remained below text.

Comment: here is my string after your changes
    <string name="Google">"<a style='text-decoration:none' href='http://www.google.com\'>Google</a>"</string>

Answer (score -6):

```
TextView text=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
final String s = text.getText();
text.setText("");
text.setText(s);
```

that's all, folks ))

Comment: Sorry, doesn't work for me: TextView creditsTextView = (TextView) dialog.getCustomView().findViewById(R.id.text_credits);
                creditsTextView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
                final CharSequence s = creditsTextView.getText();
                creditsTextView.setText("");
                creditsTextView.setText(s);