# Click on part of text and move to other activity

Tags: android

I have a text with some words which if we click on and move to other activities. 
I tried to search a lot from internet or stack overflow. Is there any technique to solve this issue?

Thanks and best regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's about specific words inside a bigger piece of text, mark the clickable words as [`URLSpan`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/URLSpan.html) and override the `URLSpan`'s `onClick(View widget)` method to start the new `Activity` - by default it will fire off on `Intent.ACTION_VIEW`. I'm sure you'll be able to find multiple examples if you do a search here on SO.

If you also want to remove the underline that is inherent to the `URLSpan`, have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4463535/1029225).

Comment: I think this link is good
http://www.chrisumbel.com/article/android_textview_rich_text_spannablestring

Answer (score -2):

simply setOnClickListener on TextView

```
textView.setOnClickListener(new OnClikListener(){
public void onClick(View v){
//here call your activity
}

});
```

Comment: i just want to click on some parts of text