# How to remove formatting from anchor link in Android strings.xml

Tags: android, css, textview, android-xml

I've got a string containing HTML  link like this:

```
<string name="text_with_link"><a href="openDocument://document1.html"><b>This</b></a> and <a href="openDocument://document2.html"><b>this</b></a> are links</string>
```

As you noticed, I want the links to be bold. That is the only formatting I want the links to have, though. However, the result looks like this:

[image]

How can I remove the underline and color from the link?

I've tried to add `style="text-decoration:none;"` in following forms

```
<a href="openDocument://document2.html" style="text-decoration:none;">

<a href="openDocument://document2.html" style="text-decoration:none !important;">

<style>a {text-decoration:none;}</style><a href="openDocument://document1.html"><b>This</b></a>
```

.. but no luck. CSS doesn't seem to work in Android strings.

Comment: Can you give the exact code that you used ?
ex <a href="openDocument://document1.html" style="text-decoration: none ;"><b>This</b></a>

Comment: Maybe [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4096851/remove-underline-from-links-in-textview-android) will be helpful

Answer (score 0):

you will have to use `Html.fromHtml` for formatting to work like this:

```
tv = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.textviewid);       
tv.setText(Html.fromHtml(getResources.getString(R.string.text_with_link)));
```

also to change link color you have to use `android:textColorLink` property in your text view XML to change the link color.

CSS does not work in android strings.

Comment: Doing that still only joins the words together without any space.

Comment: @anoniim can you post the result as image?

Comment: Sorry, I confused two issues I had, ignore my last comment. Anyway, after wrapping the text in Html.fromHtml() <a> is ignored. So there is no text decoration, but also no link. Quite surprising.