# TextView anchor link space

Tags: android, textview

I want to make a TextView with a link. I made it with combination of html and bit of java:

```
// used to enable link navigation on TextView
setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance())

// TextView with link
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="19dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:linksClickable="true"
    android:text="@string/link"/>

// @string/link
<string name="link">Test <a href="#">link</a></string>
```

However there is still one issue, the space before actual link text is underlined like this:

[image]

Why is that and how could it be fixed?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4096851/remove-underline-from-links-in-textview-android

Comment: Not a duplicate. Above post says about removing the `underline` entirely form `HyperLink`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `CDATA` in string to use `HTML` tags and use `Html.fromHtml()` method to set the text.

**Implementation below:**

Set the text using `Html.fromHtml()` in your `Activity` class.

```
TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.link)));
textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

In `strings.xml` modify as below:

```
<string name="link">Test <![CDATA[<a href="#">link</a>]]></string>
```