# TextView link underline issue

Tags: android, textview

Any ideas why the underline on the links go over the space character just before the link? You can see the underline is almost touching the character before the link, r and d.

[image]

My TextView:

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingRight="20dp"
        android:paddingTop="15dp"
        android:text="@string/register_terms"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="#BFFFFFFF"
        android:textColorLink="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="15sp" />
```

My string:

```
<string name="register_terms">By clicking this button, you agree to our <a href="https://www.google.com/">Terms &amp; Conditions</a> and <a href="https://www.google.com/">Privacy Policy</a>.</string>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link to the answer that my help you: [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49316707/textview-anchor-link-space).

They explain in details how to use `CDATA` in string to use `HTML` tags and use `Html.fromHtml()` method to set the text.

Here is an example:

Set the text using `Html.fromHtml()` in your `Activity` class.

```
TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.link)));
textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

In strings.xml modify as below:

```
<string name="link">Test <![CDATA[<a href="#">link</a>]]></string>
```

Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 0):

You can write your string in xml as :

```
<string name="register_terms">By clicking this button, you agree to our&#160;<a href="https://www.google.com/">Terms &amp; Conditions</a> and <a href="https://www.google.com/">Privacy Policy</a>.</string>
```

And declare in textview property as : `android:text="@string/register_terms"`

Or you can declare string in xml as :

```
<string name="register_terms">By clicking this button, you agree to our <![CDATA[<a href="https://www.google.com/">Terms &amp; Conditions</a>]]> and <![CDATA[<a href="https://www.google.com/">Privacy Policy</a>]]>.</string>
```

And use in activity as :

```
    TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.register_terms)));
```