# How to remove underline in hyperlink

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I have a TextView on my 'settings' activity:

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/review"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:drawablePadding="15dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="@string/review"
        android:textColor="#595959"
        android:textColorLink="#595959"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:drawableLeftCompat="@drawable/ic_review"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.055"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/view"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.876" />
```

I have defined my URL on the string.

```
<string name="review"><a href="https://play.google.com/store">Submit a review</a></string>
```

On my settings.kt page I have the following code onCreate:

```
val mTextView = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.review)

mTextView.movementMethod = LinkMovementMethod.getInstance()
```

From what I have found, I need to add a 'spannable' in relation to the above (settings.kt) but I'm not sure how to apply it, as everyone adds hyperlinks differently.

Comment: I think this is the answer to the question
[https://stackoverflow.com/a/4463535/8904397](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4463535/8904397)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you mentioned you have to add spanable
first add this function(this is a kotlin extention function for textview):

```
fun TextView.removeLinksUnderline() {
val spannable = SpannableString(text)
for (u in spannable.getSpans(0, spannable.length, URLSpan::class.java)) {
    spannable.setSpan(object : URLSpan(u.url) {
        override fun updateDrawState(ds: TextPaint) {
            super.updateDrawState(ds)
            ds.isUnderlineText = false
        }
    }, spannable.getSpanStart(u), spannable.getSpanEnd(u), 0)
}
text = spannable
```

}

then to use this function and remove underline type:

replace your textview with correct one(name of your textview)

```
txtView.removeLinksUnderline()
```

more info about kotlin extention functions: [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/kotlin-extension-function/#:%7E:text=Kotlin%20gives%20the%20programmer%20the,is%20known%20as%20Extension%20Function.)

more about removing hyperlinks: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4463535/16728174)